# Srapyrt docker deployment to heroku doesnt work as expected

Tags: python, docker, heroku, scrapy

I am fairly new on `docker` and `heroku`, i can't get my docker container to run on heroku. I know the scope might seem wide but i'll try my best to explain myself *(be patient)* after that you'll notice my problem is a one line statement.

### **What am trying to do**

To host a simple restful scraper using scrapyrt. *(scrapyrt already have a docker image on dockerhub [here](https://hub.docker.com/r/scrapinghub/scrapyrt))*

### **What i have been doing**

**1. Created a Dockerfile**

```
   //Dockerfile

   FROM scrapinghub/scrapyrt as sunflower
   COPY . /scrapyrt/project
   EXPOSE $PORT
```

**2. Run build and test my scraper**

```
//On Terminal

$ sudo docker build -t scrapyrt .
$ sudo docker run -d --name sunflower -p 9080:9080 scrapyrt
```

> i go to `http://localhost:9080/crawl.json?start_requests=true&spider_name=onlineStores` the scraper is working. Everything looks okay.

**3. Host to heroku now**

```
//On Terminal

$ heroku create sunflower-spiders
$ sudo heroku container:login
$ sudo docker build -t registry.heroku.com/sunflower-spiders/web .
$ sudo docker push registry.heroku.com/sunflower-spiders/web
$ sudo heroku container:release --app sunflower-spiders web
```

> I go to `https://sunflower-spiders.herokuapp.com` its a crashes app it say i have to go to `heroku logs --tail`

```
//heroku logs --tail

2020-04-13T09:10:53.977093+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2020-04-13T09:11:05.171071+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-04-13T09:11:05.033342+00:00 app[web.1]: usage: scrapyrt [-h] [-p PORT] [-i IP] [--project PROJECT] [-s name=value]
2020-04-13T09:11:05.033383+00:00 app[web.1]: [-S project.settings]
2020-04-13T09:11:05.033391+00:00 app[web.1]: scrapyrt: error: unrecognized arguments: scrapyrt
2020-04-13T10:35:31.260864+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=spider-sunflower.herokuapp.com request_id=bb5dfdd9-3100-420a-bcfd-22c0318f4b9a fwd="102.167.137.10" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-04-13T10:35:45.535340+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/crawl.json" host=spider-sunflower.herokuapp.com request_id=64ea25be-c596-456c-838f-33c80440de5b fwd="102.167.137.10" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

> Am i missing something

[Source Codes](https://gitlab.com/xaander1/scrapy-alt/-/archive/master/scrapy-alt-master.zip)

### Extra

```
#SCRAPINGHUB/SCRAPYRT DOCKERFILE

# To build:
# > sudo docker build -t scrapyrt .
#
# to start as daemon with port 9080 of api exposed as 9080 on host
# and host's directory ${PROJECT_DIR} mounted as /scrapyrt/project
#
# > sudo docker run -p 9080:9080 -tid -v ${PROJECT_DIR}:/scrapyrt/project scrapyrt
#

FROM ubuntu:14.04

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y python python-dev  \
    libffi-dev libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev zlib1g-dev libssl-dev wget

RUN mkdir -p /scrapyrt/src /scrapyrt/project
RUN mkdir -p /var/log/scrapyrt

RUN wget -O /tmp/get-pip.py "https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py" && \
    python /tmp/get-pip.py "pip==9.0.1" && \
    rm /tmp/get-pip.py 

ADD . /scrapyrt/src
RUN pip install /scrapyrt/src

WORKDIR /scrapyrt/project

ENTRYPOINT ["scrapyrt", "-i", "0.0.0.0"]

EXPOSE 9080
```

**Error log on heroku**
 [image: error log]

Comment: Those commands won't run when I run in normal user mode.  I don't like it either. Am starting to think I should have use the script too install my docker... I downloaded the deb files.

Comment: The `heroku` commands _definitely_ don't require `sudo`, and if your machine is configured properly the `docker` ones shouldn't, either.

Comment: Could that be causing the problem am facing...

Comment: Unlikely, but I don't know. I've never deployed Docker containers to Heroku. It's just a good idea to avoid `sudo` whenever possible.

Comment: Will look into it...fix my docker.

Comment: The crash is likely due to inability to gracefully handle a failure to open a port. The assumption the port 9080 can be used from inside a container is incorrect, the scraper should use $PORT env variable instead. `EXPOSE 9080` is [documented](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/container-registry-and-runtime#dockerfile-commands-and-runtime) to be ignored.

Comment: I experimented on that yesterday...the current build has an extra port exposed... That's is in my dorkerfile I added `EXPOSE $PORT` . The app still crashes...

Comment: On Heroku `EXPOSE xxxx` is documented to be ignored, no matter what `xxxx` is. As a sidenote, on other e.g. non-Heroku platforms including your local Docker environment, `EXPOSE xxxx` is only used with `-P` command line option (note 'P' is capital). Your code needs to start looking at $PORT env variable.

Comment: So whats do you suggest...maybe theoretically i should add a `CMD` command on my Dockerfile like this `CMD scrapyrt -p $PORT` to start **scrapyrt**

Comment: I'd suggest to check `scrapyrt` documentation to see if it accepts port as a command line option.  In `Dockerfile` the `CMD` command will conflict with existing `ENTRYPOINT`, start `scrapyrt` with either one or another.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211649/discussion-between-xaander1-and-winwiz1).